# Uniform distribution from a fractal Perlin noise function in C#

Tags: c#, random, statistics, probability, perlin-noise

My Perlin noise function (which adds up 6 octaves of 3D simplex at 0.75 persistence) generates a 2D array array of `double`s.

These numbers each come out normalized to [-1, 1], with mean at 0. I clamp them to avoid exceptions, which I think are due to floating-point accuracy issues, but I am fairly sure my scaling factor is good enough for restricting the noise output to exactly this neighborhood in the ideal case.

Anyway, that's all details. The point is, here is a 256-by-256 array of noise:

[image]

The histogram with a normal fit looks like this:

[image]

Matlab's `lillietest` is a function which applies the Lilliefors test to determine if a set of numbers comes from a normal distribution. My result was, repeatedly, 1, which means that these numbers are not normally distributed.

I would like a function `f(x)` such that, when applied to the list of values from my noise function, the results appear uniformly distributed.

I would like this function to be implementable in C# and not take minutes to run.

Once again, it shouldn't matter where the numbers come from (the question is about transforming one distribution into another, specifically a normal-like one to uniform). Nevertheless, my noise function implementation is based on [this](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html) and [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm). You can find the above array of values [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?57avc58rzzzhfzj).

Comment: That histogram looks pretty normal, but you're using uniform and normal interchangeably (they aren't). Given how perlin noise works, particularly the continuity, a somewhat normal distribution is far more likely than uniform.

Comment: So, do you want normal distribution or uniform distribution? Those two are completely different.

Comment: I want a uniform distribution, of course. As you can see, I am already getting a normal-like one. @peachykeen Where did I do that? Also, as stated, the distribution is not normal as per the Lilliefors test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oddly enough I just wrote an article on your very question:

http://ericlippert.com/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data/

There I discuss how to turn a uniform distribution into some other distribution, but of course you can use similar techniques to transform other distributions.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably be interested in one of the following (related) techniques:

- [*Probability integral transform*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform)
- [*Histogram equalization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization)